# FileZilla Server Problems locally

Tags: ftp

I have WAMP set up on my Windows 7 PC and wish to access the WAMP files on my Mac remotely so I can edit them with Coda.

So I have set up FileZilla Server. However, when I try to connect with these credentials:
Server: 192.168.1.71
User Name: admin
Password: mypass
port: 14147

It fails to connect. I have aslo tried connecting using passive mode. Have I set this up wrong? Note: I set up users by going to: Edit, then Users, then adding a user.

Am I doing this correctly or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set manualy the Port to: 14147?

And have you disabled your firewall on the Win7 maschine for testing?

You can test it with telnet from the MAC client if its installed.

Edit:

**telnet 192.168.1.71 21**

**Port: 14147 is the Adminport. To connect try the default FTP port:21!**

To connect to the admin interface try http://127.0.0.1:14147 and a blank password.

Comment: On FileZilla it's default 14147. So that's what I used on Coda. And Just tried turing off my firewall on Win7. Connection was refused straight away.

Comment: And just tried telnet, it says "Trying 192.168.1.71..." Then times out.

Comment: my filezilla run default on 21 on the normal FTP Port this is why i ask. And i couldn't find your port for WAMP oh ok... 14147 this is the admin port... this is not for a connection.